# How to use a custom repository in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, repository

I have a custom repository in my Symfony's project and I want use like a search tool. My project' structure is the following:

**P.D. UPDATED Question and code**

```
-Manager:
 * BaseManager.php
 * MyEntityManager.php
-Repository:
 * BaseRepository.php
 * MyEntityRepository.php
```

Well, I want access to my custom repository and use the following method `findByTitle`, which method should return an array with objects which description field be similar. I put a simple print (var_dump of the term entered) inside of my function to see if my browser shows it, but it isn't showed yet...

My BaseManager:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Manager;

use AppBundle\Repository\BaseRepository;

class BaseManager
{
    /**
     * @var BaseRepository
     */
    protected $repo;


    /**
     * @param BaseRepository $repo
     */
    public function __construct(BaseRepository $repo)
    {
        $this->repo = $repo;
    }

    /**
     * @param  $model
     * @return bool
     */
    public function create($model)
    {
        return $this->repo->create($model);
    }

    /**
     * @param CrudModel $model
     * @return bool
     */
    public function update($model)
    {
        return $this->repo->save($model);
    }

    /**
     * @param CrudModel $model
     * @return bool
     */
    public function delete($model)
    {
        return $this->repo->delete($model);
    }

    /**
     * @param $id
     * @return null|object
     */
    public function getOneById($id)
    {
        return $this->repo->findOneById($id);
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function all()
    {
        return $this->repo->all();
    }

}
```

MyEntityManager:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Manager;

use AppBundle\Repository\MyEntityRepository;
use AppBundle\Entity\MyEntity;

/**
 * Class MyEntityManager
 * @package AppBundle\Manager
 */
class MyEntityManager extends BaseManager{

    public function findByTitle($title){

        echo '<h1>flux of code here</h1>';
        return $this->repo->findByTitle($title);
    }

    public function findSimilars($term){
        echo '<h1>flux of code here</h1>';
        return $this->repo->findSimilars($term);
    }
}
```

BaseRepository:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

abstract class BaseRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function create($model, $autoFlush = true)
    {
        return $this->insert($model,$autoFlush);
    }

    public function save($model, $autoFlush = true)
    {
        return $this->insert($model,$autoFlush);
    }

    public function delete($model)
    {
        try{
            $this->getEntityManager()->remove($model);
            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
            return true;
        }catch (\Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function findOneById($id)
    {
        return $this->findOneBy(array('id' => $id));
    }

    public function all()
    {
        return $this->findAll();
    }

    private function insert($model, $autoFlush = true)
    {
        $this->getEntityManager()->persist($model);
        if ($autoFlush) {
            $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

MyEntityRepository:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
* Class MyEntityRepository
* @package AppBundle\Repository
*/
class MyEntityRepository extends BaseRepository{

  private function findById($id){
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('myentity')
    ->where('myentity.id = :id')
    ->setParameter('id', $id)
    ->getQuery();

    $myentity = $query->getResult();

    return $myentity;
  }

  private function findByTitle($term){
      echo '<h1>';
      var_dump($term);
      echo '</h1>',
      $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('myentity')
              ->andwhere('myentity.description = :description')
              ->setParameter('description', $term)
              ->getQuery();
      $myentity = $query->getResult();

      return $myentity;
  }
}
```

The beginning of MyEntity:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;


/**
* @ORM\Table(name="myentity")
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\MyEntityRepository")
*/
class MyEntity {

......
```

My services.yml:

```
parameters:
    app.myentity.repository.class: AppBundle\Repository\MyEntityRepository
    app.myentity.manager.class: AppBundle\Manager\MyEntityManager

services:

    app.myentity.repository:
        class: %app.myentity.repository.class%
        public: true
        factory_service: doctrine.orm.entity_manager
        factory_method: getRepository
        arguments: [ AppBundle\Entity\MyEntity ]

    app.myentity.manager:
        class: %app.myentity.manager.class%
        arguments: [@app.myentity.repository]
```

And I'm calling my service in the following way:

```
 public function searchAction(Request $request, $term){
        $manager = $this->get('app.myentity.manager');
        $result = $manager->findByTitle($term);

        echo '<h5>';
        var_dump($result);
        echo '</h5>';
        ....
    }
```

Comment: Having trouble understanding your sentences but you might check to make sure that your entity manager is correctly mapped to your entity class.  Sound like you are getting the base repository and not your custom one.

Comment: You should provide code you're trying to use.

Comment: Yes, it seems that I'm getting just my BaseRepository... but I don't see my fault @Cerad

Comment: Yes, you are right; I'm sorry if I misspoke. I updated my question and included my code. I think that now it is more clear my issue @dragoste

Comment: Verify you don't have any additional mapping files under Resources/config/doctrine as they will interfere with your annotations.  And you won't be able to access private methods if that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Damm, yes you are right. I was tired and I didn't see that big fail.... Now I can access to my method, but I have another problem. Now I get the following error: `Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Doctrine\ORM\Query could not be converted to string ` Why happen this? I just passed to `findByTitle` a string... And sorry for bother you @Cerad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I declared my function as private instead of public

```
private function findByTitle($term){
```

instead of

```
public function findByTitle($term){
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, as your question is far from being clear (esp. the last paragraph): did you only register the service, or did you also tell Symfony to use the repository for the entity (presumably `MyEntity`)? For instance, using annotations, you’d need something like this:

```
@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="The\RepositoryClass")
```

Comment: Yes, you are right; I'm sorry if I misspoke. I updated my question and included my code. I think that now it is more clear my issue

Comment: And I'm using the annotation to my repository in my Entity class